# SSDT - Can't return a table in the test result set

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tdd, sql-server-data-tools

Based on most online tutorials and based on this [presentation  from SSDT team blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ssdt/presentation-on-visual-studio-database-projects-integration-with-visual-studio-team-foundation-server/).
Specifically the following slide: 
[image: Defining test conditions]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-41-67/5826.Slide21.PNG))</sub>

```
SELECT @RC AS RC;
```

is used to return a result set that can be used in the test conditions. But I can't return a table in @RC. I want to do something like this in the test:

```
DECLARE @Result TABLE 
    (
        ColumnName1 NVARCHAR(50), 
        ColumnName2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
        ColumnName3 NVARCHAR(50)
    );
DECLARE @RC  TABLE 
    (
        ColumnName1 NVARCHAR(50), 
        ColumnName2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
        ColumnName3 NVARCHAR(50)
    );

INSERT INTO @Result EXECUTE [MyStoredProc]

SELECT @RC = @Result
SELECT @RC AS RC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be easier than what I expected, use this:

```
SELECT * FROM @Result
```

instead of this:

```
SELECT @RC = @Result
SELECT @RC AS RC
```